# Heteroscedastic Asymptotic Variance Simple Transformation

Tags: regression, linear, heteroscedasticity, linear-algebra

Let's denote the asymptotic variance under heteroscedasticity as:

$$\hat{\text{Avar}}(\hat{\beta}) = 1/N * \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i}{x_i x_i'}\right)^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i} \hat{u}^2_i x_i x_i'\right) \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i}{x_i x_i'}\right)^{-1}$$

But I would like to have that in matrix terms. First I think I can delete all 1/N, because they cancel each other out. And then I suggest this (assume the residuals can be denoted as Ω):

$$(X' X)^{-1} (X'Ω X) (X' X)^{-1}$$

Is this allowed or did I miss something?

Comment: Your first formula contains a mistake, it must be the squared residuals. And then yes, $\Omega$ would be a diagonal matrix with the squared residuals.

Comment: Great,, Thanks!

Comment: Maybe one additional thing, the asymptotic variance is something that should be nondegenerate as $N$ diverges, but here it is more like the "standard error format" which goes to 0 as $N$ becomes large. So for the *asymptotic* variance you divide by $N$ once too often.